# QUERY Data for array of set of Conditions in SELECT Oracle

Tags: oracle, select

I have a query something Like this

Set of columns : { user_id , user_details,date }

I have set of conditional values like : { 1 , AAA , 09-03-2021 } , { 2 , BBB , 08-02-2021 }

I am trying to add the conditions in same select query as I need to get the data at a same time ,

Have tried below query

SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ( user_id , user_details , date ) in ( select 1 , AAA , 09-03-2021 from dual ) ;

The above was working properly , when I use the below , I couldnt fetch Data , Can someone please if there is any provision to fetch data for all the set of conditons .

SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ( user_id , user_details , date ) in (( select 1 , AAA , 09-03-2021 from dual ) , (  select  2 , BBB , 08-02-2021 from dual ) );

Comment: "Array of set of conditions"? What "conditions" are you talking about? What you are describing are tuples of values - in some contexts there are called "records", in the database they are usually known as "rows" (although perhaps your table may have additional columns). Anyway, the most general and correct term is "tuples" - and they are definitely made up of "values", not "conditions". And they are definitely not "arrays" of anything.

Comment: @user13922012 If you'll carefully read [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), you'll find this: *2. Provide **proper** sample data*. Or [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *Help others reproduce the problem*. It is here not for fun, but to save answerer's time: when you skip such details it takes more time to write a good and complete working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax, even for a single tuple to compare to. The two cases should look like this:

```
where (user_id, user_details, date) in ( (1 , 'AAA' , to_date('09-03-2021')) )
```

and

```
where (user_id, user_details, date) in ( (1 , 'AAA' , to_date('09-03-2021')), 
                                         (2 , 'BBB' , to_date('08-02-2021')) )
```

There is no need to select anything from `DUAL` in the `IN` lists. The `IN` condition can **also** be used when the values on the right-hand side come from a table (in which case you would select three columns from that table, not from `DUAL`), but that's not what you are using here - here you are using hard-coded values, and the syntax doesn't require `SELECT` in the `IN` list.

Note that in your question you use values like `1, AAA, 09-03-2021`. I hope you know that's wrong. `1` is fine, it's a number. `AAA` not enclosed in single quotes is not a string - it will be interpreted as a column name, and an error will be thrown because your table doesn't have a column named `AAA`. And 09-03-2021 is seen as a simple arithmetic expression involving three numbers, with minus signs (subtractions) between them. If this confuses you, that's a big problem.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy , it works , regarding the representation of Data and String , I have explained it as an example whereas actual were different , hence missed the quotes and t0_date functions subconsciously